# Remove duplicated group dplyr r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(GENE= c("ENS1", "ENS2", 
"ENS3", "ENS4", "ENS1",  "ENS2", "ENS3"), group= c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

GENE  group
ENS1  1
ENS2  1
ENS3  1
ENS4  2
ENS1  3
ENS2  3
ENS3  3
```

Since groups 1 and 3 are identical I would like to remove one of them.
How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df, GENE, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
  GENE group
1 ENS1     1
2 ENS2     1
3 ENS3     1
4 ENS4     2
```

Comment: This works only for this example. When you remove row 7 from input `df <- df[-7, ]` group 1 and 3 are not identical but it will still remove group3.

Answer (score 4):

A base R option using `stack` + `unstack` + `duplicated`

```
setNames(
    type.convert(
        stack((u <- unstack(df))[!duplicated(u)]),
        as.is = TRUE
    ), names(df)
)
```

which gives

```
  GENE group
1 ENS1     1
2 ENS2     1
3 ENS3     1
4 ENS4     2
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `filter` with `!duplicated`:

```
library(dplyr)

  df %>% 
    filter(!duplicated(GENE))
```

Output:

```
  GENE group
1 ENS1     1
2 ENS2     1
3 ENS3     1
4 ENS4     2
```

Comment: This works only for this example. When you remove row 7 from input `df <- df[-7, ]` group 1 and 3 are not identical but it will still remove group3.

Comment: @Ronak Shah. Thank you for this advice. Top info as always!

Answer (score 3):

You can create an unique `key` by pasting the `GENE` value for all `group` together, keep only the unique keys in the output by joining the original `df`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(key = toString(sort(GENE))) %>%
  distinct(key, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'group') %>%
  select(-key)

df

#  group GENE 
#  <int> <chr>
#1     1 ENS1 
#2     1 ENS2 
#3     1 ENS3 
#4     2 ENS4
```

If you drop the 7th row in the data so that group 1 and group 3 are not identical it will keep rows for all the groups. I hope that is what you meant by "identical".

```
df <- df[-7, ]

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(key = toString(sort(GENE))) %>%
  distinct(key, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'group') %>%
  select(-key)

#  group GENE 
#  <int> <chr>
#1     1 ENS1 
#2     1 ENS2 
#3     1 ENS3 
#4     2 ENS4 
#5     3 ENS1 
#6     3 ENS2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `split` *df* per *group* and select the list elements which are not `duplicated` on *GENE* and `rbind` the result.

```
x <- unname(split(df, df$group))
do.call(rbind, x[!duplicated(lapply(x, `[[`, "GENE"))])
#  GENE group
#1 ENS1     1
#2 ENS2     1
#3 ENS3     1
#4 ENS4     2
```

In case *GENE* is not unique and sorted within each group this needs to be done in addition to allow detection of duplicates.

```
x <- unname(split(df, df$group))
do.call(rbind, x[!duplicated(lapply(x, function(y) sort(unique(y$GENE))))])
#  GENE group
#1 ENS1     1
#2 ENS2     1
#3 ENS3     1
#4 ENS4     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
subset(df, !duplicated(GENE))
  GENE group
1 ENS1     1
2 ENS2     1
3 ENS3     1
4 ENS4     2
```